# Should I replace a knob lock when replacing a matching deadbolt?

Tags: doors, lock, security, deadbolt

I've got three external doors with Callan knob lock and deadbolt sets. The deatbolts on two of the doors have failed due to a part on the inside that has deteriorated.

I was hoping to replace the deadbolts but keep my knob locks and keys. Is that advisable? Can a new deadbolt (different brand) bey keyed to match my old key and lock sets? Should I replace the knob locks when I replace the deadbolts and go with new keys?

Comment: Generaly the only way to keep them all keyed the same is to use the same brand. ( and you did not tell us the brands in question )  If the old deadbolts have failed than the old door knobs may not be far behind so why not just replace everything?

Comment: The current set is Callan, which I mentioned in my post. I have no idea where that came from, so it might be some builder grade garbage. I don't know what brand I want for the new locks, but possibly schlage. I'll probably just buy 3 new sets and change it all out. Thanks!

Comment: I did not know what callan knob lock meant, brand or type. I have never heard the term before.

Comment: I think a total replacement is probably a good choice, but for reference, the Callan appears to use a KW1 Kwikset keyway, so you could theoretically buy Kwikset deadbolts and rekey to match the old knob. (You could also buy 3 new Kwikset and have them keyed to your old key, if you wanted to avoid the hassle of key changeover.)

Answer (score 1):

As the comments above pointed out, it makes sense to change both the knob and the deadbolt at once. Somebody also mentioned that Callan uses the Kwikset keyway. I confirmed that my key was a kwikset keyway and bought two Kwikset smart key knob/bolt combos from home depot. Using the smartkey feature, I was able to rekey the locks at my home to match my existing key. At about $90 total, this ended up being both a reasonably priced and convenient way to continue using my existing keys on all doors.

I still have callan knob/locks on 2-3 other doors, but they are much lower traffic and have not seen the same amount of wear. Should they ever break, I can replace them with a kwikset combo.